# Rails/Globalize Hide default locale from object.translations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, globalize

I'm using Globalize gem for translating DB entities. I use `en` locale by default in the app.
When I call `podcast.translations` I got:

```
=> [#<Podcast::Translation:0x000000000da865a8 id: 2, podcast_id: 2, locale: "en", created_at: Sat, 23 Feb 2019 05:14:44 PST -08:00, updated_at: Sat, 23 Feb 2019 05:14:44 PST -08:00, name: "test">,
 #<Podcast::Translation:0x000000000da86260 id: 3, podcast_id: 2, locale: "ru", created_at: Sat, 23 Feb 2019 05:24:40 PST -08:00, updated_at: Sat, 23 Feb 2019 05:24:40 PST -08:00, name: "Русский">]
```

But I want to get translations without default `en` locale. 
I know that I can use
`podcast.translations.where.not(locale: :en)`
But maybe exist build in solution?

Comment: What does it output when typing `podcast.name` ?

Comment: @zeitnot `name` value in current locale